# How to read a value from an object

Tags: php, coinbase-php

So I got the next output from a print_r

```
Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
(
    [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] =>  18945.00
    [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] =>  USD
)
```

I'm using Coinbase SDK -> [link to github](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php)

My question is how am I supposed to read the amount value?
I'm generating that using

```
$buyPrice = $client->getSpotPrice('BTC-USD');
```

and getSpotPrice function is ->

```
 public function getSpotPrice($currency = null, array $params = [])
{
    if (strpos($currency, '-') !== false) {
        $pair = $currency;
    } else if ($currency) {
        $pair = 'BTC-' . $currency;
    } else {
        $pair = 'BTC-USD';
    }

    return $this->getAndMapMoney('/v2/prices/' . $pair . '/spot', $params);
}
```

saw something like this in the test integrations but I can't tell how to make this work:

```
public function testGetSpotPrice1()
{
    $price = $this->client->getSpotPrice();

    $this->assertInstanceOf(Money::class, $price);
}
```

Any help/ideas will be appreciated , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the value by

```
$buyPrice = $client->getSpotPrice('BTC-USD');
```

You can then use (from the source https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php/blob/master/src/Value/Money.php )...

```
$amount = $buyPrice->getAmount();
$currency = $buyPrice->getCurrency();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$BTCSellPrice = $client->getSpotPrice('BTC-USD');

//this is what you are looking for
$BTCUSD = $BTCSellPrice->getAmount();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.